# Geometric probability -- line segment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

Fellow math lovers!

It's been quite sometime since I have solved basic probability problems. I am now trying to remember how to calculate geometric probability. As far as I remember, the general formula for a geometric probability calculation is (in my case):

$$\frac{P(X-Y\text{ segment})}{P(\Omega\text{ overall line segment})}$$

Could please someone give me a hand on how to solve the most basic geometric problem:

> On the segment $[0, 1]$ two numbers $X$, $Y$ are being randomly selected. Find the probability that $X + Y \le 1$ and $X − Y > 0.1$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just a reminder that answers below will likely assume that $X$ and $Y$ are both chosen uniformly from the unit interval, and also independently of each other.

Comment: Thank you, Brian, for you remark ! I fully understand your statement and have thus taken into account this fact in prior to my original question. It is somehow, I couldn't approach the problem, because it's been quite sometime since I have solved those kind of geometric distribution problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say we have to choose two variables x and y from [0,1].
it can be demonstrated on 2D graph.
the total number of pairs of points(x,y) where x,y are in range[0,1] may be represented by the area of square formed by lines x=1,y=1,x=0,y=0.this area (which is 1 square unit) represents the total possible 
combinations of x and y such that x is in[0,1] as well y.
The points(or the combinations of x and y) which satisfies x+y<=1 are those points which are below the line x+y=1 in the plane.and likewise the points satisfying x-y>0.1 lies below the line x-y=0.1 in that plane.
so the area representing the points which satisfy above all constraints lies between the lines x-y=0.1,y=0,x+y=1 which is 0.2025
so the probability is equal to area representing allowed points divided by the area of total square=0.2025

Comment: Thank you greatly for your crystal clear explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Lets draw a plane and use the x-coordinate of any point as the value of the number X and y-coord as a value of Y so that every point "equals" one pair of numbers. You know that both X and Y are between 0 and 1, so we draw a square with the side-length of 1 as a hole field of possible outcomes. We now should draw the situations that fit our requests. All of the "good" points should be below the line y=1-x as we want that sum to be less or equal to 1. On the other hand, we want X-Y to be greater than 0.1 so the points should also be to the right of the line y=x-0.1 (so while the y is the same as on the line x gets greater). We get an area fenced by all our lines that fits our requests. Thus we calculate its area and divide it by 1 as that's the area of a hole square

Comment: Thank you greatly, for your crystal clear explanation, Alexey ! Kind regards, Varlos.